# Google places API multiple developers

Tags: android, google-api, google-places-api

We are a team working together on an android application.
unfortunately, only the one wrote the code using the google places API can run the activity, while the others can't.
We experienced the same problem with the google maps API, but that was due to the fact that we all used the same API key. 
after changing the API key (each individual the his own key) the problem stopped.
This is the code causing the crash (again, the person wrote the activity manages to run it)

```
public void refreshPlacesData() {
        Uri uri = PlaceContract.PlaceEntry.CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor data = getContentResolver().query(
                uri,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null);

        if (data == null || data.getCount() == 0) return;
        List<String> guids = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (data.moveToNext()) {
            guids.add(data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(PlaceContract.PlaceEntry.COLUMN_PLACE_ID)));
        }
        PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById(mClient,
                guids.toArray(new String[guids.size()]));     <---this is where it crash
        placeResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceBuffer places) {
                mAdapter.swapPlaces(places);
                mGeofencing.updateGeofencesList(places);
                if (mIsEnabled) mGeofencing.registerAllGeofences();
            }
        });
    }
```

and this is the error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.rubz.dvir.rubz, PID: 25203
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.rubz.dvir.rubz/com.rubz.dvir.rubz.JobRequestActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: GoogleApiClient must not be null
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3382)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3425)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:139)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1248)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: GoogleApiClient must not be null
                      at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzm.<init>(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.location.places.zzm$zzb.<init>(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.location.places.zzm$zzc.<init>(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.location.places.internal.zzl.<init>(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.location.places.internal.zzh.getPlaceById(Unknown Source)
                      at com.rubz.dvir.rubz.JobRequestActivity.refreshPlacesData(JobRequestActivity.java:445)
                      at com.rubz.dvir.rubz.JobRequestActivity.onActivityResult(JobRequestActivity.java:515)
                      at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5467)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3378)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3425) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:139) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1248) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Application terminated.
```

Comment: why are you all making separate keys? Why not simply add your **SHA-1's** into one key

Comment: Do you think it's related to the problem we are having?

Comment: clearly your log says `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: GoogleApiClient must not be null` meaning the **apiClient** you are passing to the function is null or not initialized , but having separate keys for all the developers can cause alot of fuss

Comment: Is the SHA1 key is global to the project and all the developers can use the same one? does each user should have it's own google services json file?

Comment: nope , you all get your **SHA-1** and add it to one api key , and then use that json file only in the app , and then that code will run on every ones system

Comment: How can we add multiple SHA1  to one api key?

Comment: let me post an answer , cannot post image here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple  **SHA-1's** to your places api , goto [cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/)

and then select Google Places Api, restrict your Api , and then add SHA's

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: got to the link , then choose the project on which you guys are working on

Comment: Life saver. Thanks